# why defcustom variable is not seeable from describe symbol?

Tags: defcustom

take org-brain-path for example:

```
(defcustom org-brain-path (expand-file-name "brain" org-directory)
  "The root directory of your org-brain.

`org-mode' files placed in this directory, or its subdirectories,
will be considered org-brain entries."
  :group 'org-brain
  :type '(directory))
```

I want to check its current value with `describe-symbol org-brain-path`, but I cannot find `org-brain-path` in `describe-symbol` list.

Why and how to check the current value?

Answer (score 1):

```
(require 'org-brain)
```

is needed in order to make the `defcustom` variables it defines become available.

Comment: More specifically, the definition must have been *evaluated*, and that typically happens by *loading* the library in question (which the call to `require` will ensure has happened).